# Book about the last female vampire-lycan hybrid

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

I read part of a book about a girl who is stuck looking as a 22 year old even though she is centuries old. Her mum was a vampire queen and her dad was a lycan alpha but they were killed. She is a vampire-lycan hybrid and the last one of her kind. I think her name was Camilla. Also remember that the male lead was Lucas I think and each main character had their own chapter.

I read a bit of it yesterday on Facebook but can't find the post again today.

Comment: You don't need to add your name on the post, it's already attached by default. Also have you tried looking through your browsing history if you looked through a browser?

Comment: Was on my phone tried looking through my seen posts  but its not there

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it alongside the voting buttons.

Answer (score 3):

This is [*Alpha's Hybrid Mate*](https://www.ficfun.com/novel/1962051-Alpha%27s-Hybrid-Mate.html) by Alcione02. It does not appear to be a published work. Your description matches pretty well, the 3 characters being Camilla, Liam and Lucas.

> Alpha Liam Stanford- High Alpha of the largest and strongest pack in both North and South American continent. At the age of 28 , he hasn't found his mate yet. He's a player and he's losing his hope in finding her. That was until Camilla Castillejo came to town.
>
> Camilla Castillejo- the new girl in town. Unknown to everyone, she's not new in town. She lived in that town way before the wolf pack resided there. the truth is, she's a 900 year old vampire, but a pure blood vampire-lycan hybrid. The strongest of her kind.
>
> Now that Camilla and Liam found each other , will they be happy? What if threats arises and come between them?

---

Found with the Google query `"vampire-lycan" hybrid "camilla"`.

Comment: I think thats it by the sounds of it thanks for the help